# Node.js : TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I know it's about circular reference. But I can't find out what's wrong in my code.
Following is full error message:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at Object.stringify (native)
at Object.DataModel.getDataData (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/models/dataModel.class.js:46:26)
at SocketController.handle (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/controllers/socketController.class.js:647:59)
at Object.SocketRouter.router (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/routes/socketRouter.js:25:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/app.js:190:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at onReceivePackData (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/app.js:244:24)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/app.js:154:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
/root/Rhythm-LvDong-Release/models/dataModel.class.js:45
    console.log("TESTCASE1:" + detail);
```

And following is the code:
First:dataModel.class.js:46:26

```
getDataData: function (dataType, detail) {
    var data = {};
    data.type = 'data';
    data.content = {};
    data.content.dataType = dataType;
    if (detail == 0) {
        data.content.detail = 0;
    } else {
        data.content.detail = (detail || {});
    }
    console.log("TESTCASE1:" + detail);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));//46th line
    return JSON.stringify(data);
};
```

Second:socketController.class.js:647:59

```
var room = GetRoom(socket.roomId);
if (room == null)
    break;
if (!SendMessage(socket.userId, DataModel.getDataData('RefreshRoom', room))) {//the 647th line
}
```

Then some functions I called:

```
//SendMessage
function SendMessage(userId, message)
{
    if (!streamSockets[userId])
        return false;
    streamSockets[userId].send(message);
    return true;
}
//GetRoom
function GetRoom(roomId)
{
    var room = null;
    if (roomId >= 0) {
        for (var i in RoomList) {
            if (roomId == RoomList[i].id) {
                room = RoomList[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return room;
}
```

Please help me find out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: What are you storing in `RoomList`? It seems to me that `detail` (which, following your code, is a "room"), might be causing the serialization problem.

Comment: `RoomList` likely to have circular reference I suppose, which causes the issue

Comment: Thank you for your response. RoomList is an array stores RhythmRoom struct.
I create room like this:
var room = new RhythmRoom(totalRoomNumber.get(), title, password, songMd5, socket.userId, limit, 0, 1);
                    
socket.roomId = totalRoomNumber.get();
                    totalRoomNumber.up();
                    var roomMember = new RhythmRoomMember(socket.userId, 0);
                    room.member.push(roomMember);
                    room.hostId = socket.userId;
                    RoomList.push(room);

Answer (score 0):

Change line:

```
    data.content.detail = (detail || {});
```

to:

```
    data.content.detail = detail || {};
```

I have been caught by a similar parentheses issue before

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the reason for causing circular reference.

Comment: what's stored in `RoomList`?

Comment: What I stored in RoomList is RhythmRoom struct
function RhythmRoom(id, title, password, songMd5, hostId, limit, status, memNum) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title || "";
    this.password = password || "";
    this.songMd5 = songMd5 || "";
    this.hostId = hostId || "";
    this.limit = limit || 0;
    this.status = status || 0;
    this.memNum = memNum || 0;
    this.matchMd5 = "";
    this.endTimer = null;
    this.member = [];
};

Comment: And this is what stored in member:
    var room = new RhythmRoom(totalRoomNumber.get(), title, password, songMd5, socket.userId, limit, 0, 1);
                    socket.roomId = totalRoomNumber.get();
                    totalRoomNumber.up();
                    var roomMember = new RhythmRoomMember(socket.userId, 0);
                    room.member.push(roomMember);
                    room.hostId = socket.userId;
                    RoomList.push(room);